# appDisconnect is executing before the code in roomdisconnect is executing in RED5

Tags: red5

I have both roomDisconnect and appDiconnect  overridden in my red5 application.

Form roomDiconnect ,a no:of functions are invoked.While running the application, before completing the execution of these functions, the appDisconnect is getting called.

Is there anyway to delay the appDisconnect call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No,

you can't change the Red5 API behaviour.
Just use either roomDisconnect or appDisconnect but not both.

From my experience appDisconnect is more reliable. But with latest versions of Red5 roomDisconnect could be reliable too.

Sebastian